# C++: How to override method of a specific class with same interface

Tags: c++, inheritance, interface

I have a situation where I need to inherit from two classes with same interface, but to override them separately and I definitely cannot tweak interfaces. See code example below

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo
{
    virtual ~Foo() = default;
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

struct Derived : public Foo<int>, public Foo<double>
{
#if 0 // having something like this would be great, but unfortunately it doesn't work
    void Foo<int>::foo() override
    {
        std::cout << "Foo<int>::foo()" << std::endl;
    }

    void Foo<double>::foo() override
    {
        std::cout << "Foo<double>::foo()" << std::endl;
    }
#endif
};
```

Comment: its not clear what this is supposed to achieve. For virtual methods it is determined by the dynamic type of the object which method to call. Ie you call `f.foo()` and then the type of `f` determines which `foo` to call. When `f` is a `Derived` then what `foo` should be called?

Comment: You can use intermediate classes that override the methods separately.

Comment: can you show an example of how you would call the two methods from `Derived` ?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number
```const Foo<int> &f = Derived{}; f.foo();```

Comment: and this should call the `Foo<double>` overload while `Foo<double>* f = new Dervided();` should call the other one?

Comment: yes, that's right

Comment: then you actually dont want runtime polymorphism. [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) might help

Comment: No, runtime polymorphism is actually what I need, but I think that describing a problem I actually want to solve here is too much

Comment: upd: Ah, now when @Dmitry Kuzminov sent a code example, I got what you meant. Yes, this could be also a valid answer, sorry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always define intermediate classes that declare their own interfaces:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct Foo
{
    virtual ~Foo() = default;
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

struct ProxyFooInt : public Foo<int>
{
    virtual void fooInt() = 0;
    
    void foo() override
    {
        return fooInt();
    }
};

struct ProxyFooDouble : public Foo<double>
{
    virtual void fooDouble() = 0;
    
    void foo() override
    {
        return fooDouble();
    }
};

struct Derived : public ProxyFooInt, public ProxyFooDouble
{
    void fooInt() override
    {
        std::cout << "Foo<int>::foo()" << std::endl;
    }

    void fooDouble() override
    {
        std::cout << "Foo<double>::foo()" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

A more advanced solution would be to use CRTP:

```cpp
template<typename D>
struct CrtpFooInt : public Foo<int>
{
    void foo() override
    {
        return static_cast<D*>(this)->fooInt();
    }
};

template<typename D>
struct CrtpFooDouble : public Foo<double>
{
    void foo() override
    {
        return static_cast<D*>(this)->fooDouble();
    }
};

struct Derived : public CrtpFooInt<Derived>, public CrtpFooDouble<Derived>
{
    void fooInt()
    {
        std::cout << "Foo<int>::foo()" << std::endl;
    }

    void fooDouble()
    {
        std::cout << "Foo<double>::foo()" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: using intermediate classes is an okayish idea that i also thought of, but sometimes they need to share some state and it'd be a heck of a pain to get working right

Comment: In my solution the state is shared in the `Derived` class exactly as you would share in your example. The intermediate classes just "rename" the methods.

Comment: Ah, sorry, you're actually right

Comment: I got inspired by this CRTP example, so I came up with a way to get rid of some boilerplate https://stackoverflow.com/a/70531042/10961484

Answer (score 3):

Another creative way to solve this problem would be to use an ability to add some overloading to distinguish between different invocations of `foo()`:

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo
{
    virtual ~Foo() = default;
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

template<typename T>
struct Tag{};

template<typename T>
struct Overloader : public Foo<T>
{
    virtual void foo(Tag<T>) = 0;

    void foo() override
    {
        foo(Tag<T>{});
    }
};

struct Derived : public Overloader<int>, public Overloader<double>
{
    void foo(Tag<int>) override
    {
        std::cout << "Foo<int>::foo()" << std::endl;
    }

    void foo(Tag<double>) override
    {
        std::cout << "Foo<double>::foo()" << std::endl;
    }
};
```